# Google Analytics API v3 with PHP

Tags: php, google-analytics-api

I am using "Google Analytics API v3 with PHP" (https://github.com/wanze/Google-Analytics-API-PHP) using "Web applications" but I am getting following error.

```
array(2) {
  ["http_code"]=> int(401)
  ["error"]=> array(3) {
    ["errors"]=> array(1) {
      [0]=> array(5) {
        ["domain"]=> string(6) "global"
        ["reason"]=> string(9) "authError"
        ["message"]=> string(19) "Invalid Credentials"
        ["locationType"]=> string(6) "header"
        ["location"]=> string(13) "Authorization"
      }
    }
    ["code"]=> int(401)
    ["message"]=> string(19) "Invalid Credentials"
  }
}
```

Please anyone reply for this one?
Thanks

Comment: AS it is mentioning in error - "Invalid Credentials", please check your credential.

Comment: Hi Kamal, I am using correct  client id, client secret and account id (ga:xxxxxxx) any thing wrong or setting apart from this?

Comment: Check this working example - "Hello Analytics" on https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-php and replace your "service account email" and "path of .p12" file.. It seems to be working correct.

Comment: I am using web application not service account. Could you please suggest for web application?

Comment: Can you please add the code of how you defined $client?

Comment: This is the code  
    $ga = new GoogleAnalyticsAPI(); 
    $ga->auth->setClientId($client_id);
    $ga->auth->setClientSecret($client_secret);
    $ga->auth->setRedirectUri($redirect_uri);

Comment: Also getting following error after using service accoutn email

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_Auth_Exception' with message 'Error refreshing the OAuth2 token...

Comment: "Error refreshing the OAuth2 token - Invalid grant", I would suggest you to give the permission from google analytics account API Access tab in API console.

Comment: I have enabled the Analytics API.

Comment: So still showing error or working?

Comment: Yes, still showing the same error :(